# Where is a vuex(vue) instance stored at? in what format? and how is the size limit of it?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I can kinda understand that a vuex instance(or store) is included in a vue instance as $store property.

However, where is it stored at?

Can I say it is stored on client memory with a vue instance?

What is its format? Can I say its format is "Javascript(or vue) object"?

And what can be its size limit?

It sound like there should be assumption to answer this(?), but it is bit hard to clarify it because there is not much data about this question like other data stores such as Cookie or Session.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought your question was interesting and didn't know the correct answer. After doing some research, it seem the term used in the [Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to describe where **state is abstracted to** is "**a global singleton**". And the **state is stored in memory**, as you suggested.

Here is a definition of a singleton, [derived from Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/15830/singleton):

"A singleton is a class that allows only a single instance of itself to be created and gives access to that created instance. It contains static variables that can accommodate unique and private instances of itself. It is used in scenarios when a user wants to restrict instantiation of a class to only one object. This is helpful usually when a single object is required to coordinate actions across a system."

I also found this article helpful as the style was slightly more engaging: https://codeburst.io/javascript-global-variables-vs-singletons-d825fcab75f9

I don't think there is a given size limit and so I assume **your main constraint is the size of memory available** (and practical constraints presented by the impacts on performance and maintainability as the state grows, of course).

There are also plugins available that will allow you to ensure that the Vuex state persists - after browser reloads, for example. I think they make use of the webStorage API (storing in localStorage or sessionStorage). [Here is an example](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist).